# Is it fine to ask what are tools that could solve your problem?

Tags: discussion

Say you're confronted with a new problem and you don't know what tools exist to solve it. Is it fine to create a question describing your problem and asking what tools are used for that task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are "What should I use to do x?" questions really on-topic and good?](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good)

Answer (score 5):

Generally I would think it would be better just to describe the problem you're having.  "What tool should I use" is really just a subset of "which tech should I use" which ends up just being a collections of links.

Comment: So I should go on and just ask: "how do I make an animation using programming to coordinate the positions of the objects in function of time?"

Comment: @Do Yep! "*How do I do X*" is an answerable question.